400 при попытке загрузки модуля api-maps@3
Ограничение по referers в настройках ключа поставил.



Александр, на скриншоте среди параметров запроса есть параметр Referer. В нём передаётся jamburgers.ru. Такой домен не указан среди ограничений. Проверьте, пожалуйста, настройки.
